# What is the best way ToggleShow by JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How can I show or hide element by JQuery like bellow example:

```js
function toggleShow(itemId){
  ...
}
```

```css
#toggle-item{
  diplay:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="toggle-item">ToggleShow Item</div>
<button onclick="toggleShow('toggle-item')">ToggleShow</button>
```

I answered my question ... but is there a better or more complete than my answer ? I hope there is no better way with JQuery ...

Answer (score 1):

We can use toggle method. It works between hide() and show() for the selected elements.

```js
function toggleShow(itemId){
  $("#" +itemId).toggle();
}
```

```css
#toggle-item{
  diplay:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="toggle-item">ToggleShow Item</div>
<button onclick="toggleShow('toggle-item')">ToggleShow</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

we can do it by bellow code:

```js
function toggleShow(itemId){
  if($(`#${itemId}`).css("display")!='none')
    $(`#${itemId}`).hide();
  else
  {
    $(`#${itemId}`).show();
  }
}
```

```css
#toggle-item{
  diplay:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="toggle-item">ToggleShow Item</div>
<button onclick="toggleShow('toggle-item')">ToggleShow</button>
```